# Disable swipe to open NavigationDrawer but enable to change of activity

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, swipe-gesture

I have an activity.Inside I added a NavigationDrawer.

I'd like to disable the swipe left-right to open my NavigationDrawer. I could only open it if I click in the button.

However, I want to go back to the previous page if I do a swipe left-right.

I'm able to disable the swipe for the menu, but it also disables the swipe to go back to previous page.

How can I do it ?

Here's my code :

```
    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
    mToogle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);

    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToogle);
    mToogle.syncState();

    //this is how I lock my menu
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    NavigationView navigation = (NavigationView)findViewById(R.id.menu_navigation);

    navigation.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId())
            {  
                case R.id.mes_cours:
                    Intent cours = new Intent(ModifierBranche.this,MesCours.class);
                    startActivity(cours);
                    return true;
                case R.id.mes_branches:
                     finish();
                    startActivity(getIntent());
                    return true;
            }
            return true;

        }
    });

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}


//the sub-class
class MyGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener
{

    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                           float velocityX, float velocityY) {

        if(event2.getX() > event1.getX()){
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    ModifierBranche.this, MesBranches.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

@UPDATE - ERROR

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dasilvadd.students/com.example.dasilvadd.students.ModifierBranche}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316)
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.FrameLayout$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$LayoutParams
                                                                                at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.isDrawerView(DrawerLayout.java:1421)
                                                                             at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.java:677)
                                                                                at com.example.dasilvadd.students.ModifierBranche.onCreate(ModifierBranche.java:64)
                                                                                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5372)
                                                                                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1104)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2349) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:159) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1316) 
                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176) 
                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046) 
                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862) 
                                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

my xml file:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
tools:context="com.example.dasilvadd.students.ModifierBranche">

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ETBranche"
        android:layout_width="381dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bModifier"
        android:layout_width="376dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:onClick="ModifierBranche"
        android:text="Modifier"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:id="@+id/menu_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"></android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding id to drawer layout and then using it like

```
mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED, findViewById(R.id.right_drawer));
```

It will only disable swipe for drawer not for other things. Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It kills my app.. You meant I should replace the line i commented with the one you gave me ?

Comment: I added, It's in this line :  at com.example.dasilvadd.students.ModifierBranche.onCreate(ModifierBranche.java:64) which is the line u gave me..

Comment: Try changing the id , give id for drawer layout

Comment: yeah in my answer change id to your id as  findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project